# Python multiple database results in one update

Tags: python, mysql, sql, sql-update

I would like to update several database results in one row.

My Code:

```
sql_client = "SELECT pd.prj_id, pd.dl_id, pd.name, pd.email FROM projects_doc pd JOIN reminder rm ON pd.prj_id = rm.prj_id WHERE doc_typ = 'assignment' ORDER BY pd.id ASC;"
result = cursor.execute(sql_client)
result = cursor.fetchall()

for row in result:
       sql_prj_id = row['prj_id']
       sql_dl_id = row['dl_id']
       sql_dl_name = row['name']
       sql_dl_email = row['email']
```

**Example Output:**

- 1, 544, TestName1, test@testname1.com
- 2, 255, TestName4, test@testname4.com
- 2, 256, TestName5, test@testname5.com
- 2, 257, TestName6, test@testname6.com
- 3, 188, TestName7, test@testname7.com

How can I update my table so that the following result comes to an end?

**Table structure**

```
prj_id, dl_id, dl_name, dl_email
```

**End result** (example)

- 1; 544; TestName1; test@testname1.com
- 2; 255, 256, 258; TestName4, TestName5, TestName6; test@testname4.com, test@testname5.com, test@testname6.com
- 3; 188; TestName7; test@testname7.com

Comment: What do you mean *update*? Do you want that output in Python or to overwrite existing MySQL table data? If the latter, how to handle different rows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider MySQL's dialect-specific aggregate function [group_concat](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat):

```sql
SELECT pd.prj_id, 
       GROUP_CONCAT(pd.dl_id) AS grp_ids, 
       GROUP_CONCAT(pd.name) AS grp_name, 
       GROUP_CONCAT(pd.email) AS grp_email 
FROM projects_doc pd 
JOIN reminder rm ON pd.prj_id = rm.prj_id 
WHERE doc_typ = 'assignment' 
GROUP BY pd.prj_id
ORDER BY pd.id ASC;
```

However, it is not clear how you want to run *update* since more rows would be in original table than above aggregate query. Consider creating a new table from above query:

```sql
CREATE TABLE new_table AS <above SELECT query>
```

Or better yet keep your original long format which provides more efficient storage, scalability, query maintainability, and referential integrity as nested lists in columns are usually for reporting than table structure. And simply create a view from this query. Views are stored queries for use elsewhere even in application level like Python and can even be queried themselves.

```sql
CREATE VIEW new_view AS <above SELECT query>

SELECT * FROM new_view WHERE prj_id = 1;
```